# How to use the one form twice or thrice on a single page?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

I have one form and I am displaying it twice on the page. I mean, I am displaying one form at the bottom and the same will display in the popup once the user clicks on the Contact Us button.

**form.php**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="enquiry">
   <div class="form-list">
      <div class="fields mb-3">
        <label>Your Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
      <div class="fields">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="phoneno" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
 <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <?php include('form.php'); ?> // displaying on the page
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contact Us</button>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
  <!--form in popup-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <?php include('form.php'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now my issue is, I am getting the popup in the form but when I submit the form then I am not getting any data but if I submit the form which is in the main tag that is working.

if I comment on the form which is inside the main tag and fill the form which is in the popup then it's working.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your form appears to have no `action` attribute. Where is it sending the data? What are you seeing be sent in the Console? Any Errors?

Comment: @Twisty, I apologise for the late reply, I am using ajax for submitting data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

The modern HTML5 specification does not allow two forms in the same document to have the same name, therefore you are only getting the contents of the first one found. (emphasis added below)

[The name attribute represents the form's name within the forms collection. The value must not be the empty string, and **the value must be unique amongst the form elements in the forms collection** that it is in, if any.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-form-name)

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: @user9437856 what do you need the name attribute on the form for to begin with? If this is actually the issue, then simply removing it should fix it.

Comment: @CBroe, I did but nothing is happening

Comment: @user9437856 I said _if_ that was the problem, I didn't specifically go look up whether this would prevent submission. I can't reproduce your problem though, if I create a static HTML document from your code with the form embedded in both places, then both can be submitted fine, browser dev tools shows it sending the same parameters with no problem in each case.